# Trigger JavaScript event that fires after client side control is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Good day,

I have a web page where the user makes a selection in a dropdown.

As soon as the item in the dropdown is selected, a Kendo grid appears and displays a list of records retrieved via an API call that returns JSON.

I have written code that does certain modifications to the html table that is generated when the grid displays, but this code is triggered by a button at the moment. This is not the behavior I want.

I need to somehow fire an event after the grid renders so that the code is executed automatically and not triggered by a button.

Is there a possibility that via JQuery I could somehow bind an event to fire after the grid control has finished rendering?

P.S. None of the existing Kendo grid events in the documentation work for what I need, not even the datasource "requestEnd", because at that moment in time, the HTML for the grid has not been generated in the page. An event like "postRender" or something like that would be ideal if it existed.

Comment: Sorry for challenging you but what are those HTML transformation in the HTML that you need to do? Maybe there is a different way and you can get the _correct_ HTML directly rendered without post intervention?

Answer (score 0):

Detecing 'rendering' is hard. Firefox has a `MozAfterPaint` event but its not standard, and I don't know how you would ensure it only fired for your particular event.

Alternatively you could try looking at DOM Mutation events but they are not well supported either, and there still may be a delay between the DOM changing and the grid being updated in the browser UI.

Your best bet would be to modify the grid HTML to output some JS which triggers a pre-defined callback.

Answer (score 0):

When your javascript is running before HTML content has bee rendered, try using `setTimeout(function () {}, 0)` to "pause" the JavaScript execution to let the rendering threads catch up. So your call pretty much looks like this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataBound: function(e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("dataBound");
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Read more about: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)